# three.js aoMap is not rendering on uv2 while lightmap is rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js

We are trying to set the aoMap with three.js, but it is not rendering, while lightMap is working on model

Code for setting uv2 into geometry:

```
// instantiate a loader
    var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();

    // load a resource
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        'temp-models/binary/door-boot-01.json',
        // Function when resource is loaded
        function ( geometry, materials ) {
            geometry.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
            geometry.mergeVertices();

            geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );
            // self.setupOBJCAR(geometry, materials, self.car.urls.obj[0]);
            // return;
            loader.load(
                // resource URL
                'temp-models/binary/door-boot-02.json',
                // Function when resource is loaded
                function ( geo2, materials ) {
                    geo2.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
                    geo2.mergeVertices();

                    geo2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geo2 );
                    var uvs = geo2.attributes.uv.array;
                    geometry.addAttribute( 'uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );
                    // console.log(geometry.toJSON());

                    //Creting Mesh with aoMap in all materials.
                }
            ));
```

Example link:

http://design.girnarsoft.com/centraljs/creta3d/index-ao.html

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with a `PlaneGeometry`, a single material, and the minimum number of light sources to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley
Seems there is issue with lights. Actually we have used Direction, Point and ambientLight. As I have removed Direction and Point light it is visible.